# How to manage content when show on frontend in php?

Tags: php

I am inserting post in DB from backend using ckEditor. I am inserting post with some html tags and it stored in DB like:

```
<h1 style="font-size: 20px; color: blue; margin: 0 auto;">Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text</h1>
<h1 style="font-size: 20px; color: blue; margin: 0 auto;">Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text</h1>
```

When i fetch content from DB I need to show some content on front end so I used below code in my php code to print some content:

```
limit_words($post['content'], 100);
function limit_words($string, $word_limit){
    $words = explode(" ",$string);
    return implode(" ",array_splice($words,0,$word_limit));
}
```

This returns me something like:

```
<h1 style="font-size: 20px; color: blue; margin: 0 auto;">Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text</h1>
    <h1 style="font-size: 20px;
```

And my html breaks. Can anyone help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance for your attention.

Comment: Your requirement is not very clear, so I'm just going to comment rather than answer.  If you truly want to limit the words, you'll most likely need to strip all the HTML out first using [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php), which means you won't be able to show markup in the "Excerpt".  Otherwise, you'll have to find some way (seems VERY difficult to do correctly / properly).

Comment: you want to display the exact  words stored in the `DB`?

Comment: @julekgwa: Yes I want to display exact words but need to show limited words.